# Сохранение множества картинок в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Вообщем такое дело, решил потренироваться в traits и заодно избавится от одного расширения для сохранения картинок и в итоге написал такой код:

```
trait UploadFilesTrait {

public function upload($model_name, $field, $path_to_file = 'undefined', $oldFile = '') {
    if ($model_name->validate()) {
        $name_image = $model_name->$field->baseName . '.' . $model_name->$field->extension;
        $new_name_image = 'upload/temp_files/' . time() . '.' . $model_name->$field->extension;
        $path = 'upload/' . $path_to_file . '/' . $name_image;
        shell_exec('convert ' . $new_name_image . ' -auto-orient -quality 90 ' . $path);
        $model_name->$field->saveAs($path);

        @unlink($new_name_image);
        if ($oldFile != '') {
            @unlink($oldFile);
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function uploadGallery($model_name, $field, $path_to_file = 'undefined') {
    if ($model_name->validate()) {
        foreach ($model_name->$field as $file) {
            $randTempNameFile = time() . '_' . $file->baseName;
            $name_image = $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
            $new_name_image = 'upload/temp_files/' . $randTempNameFile . '.' . $file->extension;
            $path = 'upload/' . $path_to_file . '/' . $name_image;
            shell_exec('convert ' . $new_name_image . ' -auto-orient -quality 90 ' . $path);
            $file->saveAs($path);

            @unlink($new_name_image);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Использую его в контроллере так:

```
$newTicketText = new TicketsText();
    if ($newTicketText->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $newTicketText->ticketsFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($newTicketText, 'ticketsFiles');
        if ($newTicketText->ticketsFiles) {
            $this->uploadGallery($newTicketText, 'ticketsFiles','tickets');
        }

        $newTicketText->date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $newTicketText->user_type = TicketsText::TYPE_USER_NORMAL;
        $newTicketText->save(false);

        $newTextFiles = new TicketsFiles();
        foreach ($newTicketText->ticketsFiles as $ticketFile) {
            $newTextFiles->ticket_id = $newTicketText->ticket_id;
            $newTextFiles->ticket_text_id = $newTicketText->id;
            $newTextFiles->file = 'upload/tickets/' . $ticketFile;
            $newTextFiles->save(false);
        }

        return $this->refresh();
    }
```

Суть проблемы в том, что при попытке сохранение 2 или 3 картинок, сохраняется только одна последняя, при этом она есть только в базе физически она не сохраняется. Поэтому прошу помощи.
Ну и часть кода где я цепляю картинки:

```
<div class="attach">
    <div class="attach__wrapp-label">
        <label class="attach__label" id="label-file1" for="file1">
            <?= Html::activeFileInput($newTicketText, 'ticketsFiles[]', ['multiple' => true, 'class' => 'left clip-input1 attach__input', 'id' => 'file1']); ?>
                <span class="attach__icon s-di-vertical-m"></span>
                <span class="attach__text s-di-vertical-m clip-input-txt1">Прикрепить файл</span>
            </label>
            <?= Html::error($newTicketText, 'ticketsFiles[]', ['class' => 'help-block']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вообще после нескольких десяток попыток я нашел в чем проблема и она не только в том, что я модель создавал вне цикла. Вообщем вот код:

```
if ($newTicket->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $newTicket->status = Tickets::STATUS_OPEN_TICKET;
    $newTicket->new_text = false;
    $newTicket->ticketFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($newTicket, 'ticketFiles');
    $newTicket->save(false);

    $newTextTicket = new TicketsText();
    $newTextTicket->ticket_id = $newTicket->id;
    $date_time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $newTextTicket->date_time = $date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $newTextTicket->text = $newTicket->tickets_text;
    $newTextTicket->user_type = TicketsText::TYPE_USER_NORMAL;
    $newTextTicket->save(false);

    if ($newTicket->ticketFiles) {
        $manyFile = $this->uploadGallery($newTicket, 'ticketFiles','tickets');

        foreach ($manyFile as $ticketFile) {
            $newTextFiles = new TicketsFiles();
            $newTextFiles->ticket_id = $newTicket->id;
            $newTextFiles->ticket_text_id = $newTextTicket->id;
            $newTextFiles->type_file = $ticketFile['type'];
            $newTextFiles->file = $ticketFile['path'];
            $newTextFiles->name_file = $ticketFile['name'];
            $newTextFiles->save(false);
        }
    }

    return $this->refresh();
}
```

Правда тут еще данные добавились, но суть ясна.

Answer (score 0):

Создавайте модель($newTextFiles = new TicketsFiles();) внутри цикла, то есть просто передвинте эту строчку на одну строчку вниз.